# How to use TableAdapter to update a row into SQL database (C#)

Tags: c#, sql

Here is my code:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        if (SaveChanges(conn, trans, user))
        {
            trans.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            trans.Rollback();
        }            
    }
}

private bool SaveChanges(SqlConnection sqlConnection, SqlTransaction transaction, User aUser)
{
    try
    {
        dt = new UserInformationDataSet.UserInformationDataTable();
        using (var adpt = new UserInformationTableAdapter())
        {
            adpt.Connection = sqlConnection;
            adpt.Transaction = transaction;

            UserInformationDataSet.UserInformationRow row = dt.NewUserInformationRow();
            row.Name = aUser.Name;
            row.Email = aUser.Email;
            row.Position = aUser.Position;
            row.IDNumber = aUser.IDNumber;
            row.Sex = aUser.IsMale;
            row.CreateDate = aUser.CreateDate;
            row.Password = aUser.Password;

            int debug = adpt.Update(row);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Showe(e.ToString());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is the picture of my database structure:
[image]

The `debug` always will be 0, which means nothing updated. How can I do it correctly? I am not going to allow any user to change `Email` (the Primary Key) now. However, if I want to user to be able to change everything including the Primary Key, how can I do it? My friend told me a solution: make a `List<User> allUser`, that contains every `user` information from the database. When a user makes a change, then update in the `allUser` first, and then clean every row in the database and re-add them with `allUser`. I tried, and it works but I do want to DO it so, because I do not want to remove every row and re-add it again, that is just wasting time and if two users using the database at the same time and both of them make changes, then the first one's change will be overwritten by the last one. So, I am wondering that is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: why don't you create a stored procedure to do the update vs trying to do this using table adapter..

Comment: Because I am trying to avoid the query statement (Such as `SELECT`, `DELETE`, or `UPDATE`). The reason is this class does not know which column that user changed. Other class just passed a single changed user to this class and this class should be able to update.

Comment: well something are easier done.. have you tried consulting the MSDN documentation there are examples on how to do this.. I would recommend doing things in a much easier fashion you could have had this completed and working by now if you took the time to convert this into using stored procedures just my take on the issue

Comment: Do you have properly specified the `UpdateCommand` property?

Comment: @MethodMan Yes, I checked MSDN documentation and follow the instruction, but I do not know why my code does not work. However, thank you for sharing.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Technically, I have no problem for specified the `updateCommand`. But what about if I have 10 or more columns in a table, if I am using `UpdateCommand`, my code would be too long and hard to maintained. I have no problem with using `TableAdapter.Insert` and `TableAdapter.Delete` I just wondering why I cannot use `Update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked `.Update()` function which, generate by the Visual Studio. There is nothing in it but only the name of the function. However, `.Insert()` and `.Delete()` have the actual code to insert and delete row into the database. I do not know why the Visual Studio does not do the update automatically, but to make a guess, I think I have to use `SqlCommandBuilder` to add some query statement for that. Anyway, what I am doing now is create a new query for the `UserInformationTableAdapter()` called `UpdateUser` and I manually add the query statement for it. Now, everything is fine.